# Service para gerenciar sessões PHP (Symfony2)

Tags: php, session, symfony-2, services

Preciso criar um Service em PHP para gerenciar as Sessions de uma aplicação, alguém tem um exemplo prático para isso?

PS: sou iniciante! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é necessário criar um serviço para gerenciar as sessões em aplicações Symfony, uma vez que ele já possui embutido um serviço para esse fim, chamado `session`.

Se você quiser usar o `session` em seus controladores, basta chamá-lo pelo id do serviço:

```
$this->get('session');
```

... ou usar o método `getSession()` do `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`:

```
$this->getSession();
```

Se você quiser criar um serviço e injetar a sessão nele (por meio do construtor), basta passar esse mesmo `session` na definição do serviço:

```
service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
    arguments: [ @session ]
```

Sacou? :)

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado Rodrigo!

Comment: @mauriciocaserta Boa! :)